# How do I post an individual element of a model's collection to an action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model that contains a collection. I want to wrap each individual `EditorFor` in a form that posts to an action with a single element as the parameter. i.e:

```
class ModelWithCollection
{
    List<ElementModel> Elements { get; set; }
}

class ElementModel
{
    int Field { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult ElementAction(ElementModel viewModel)
{

}
```

However, my `viewModel` doesn't have the properties populated. I can understand this, as the editor renders the ids as things like `Elements[0].Field`. Rather where the action would like just `Field`.

How can I get around this?

---

I don't think I can manually build the post using jquery or something as it include uploading a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is an overload of `EditorFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407399%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that takes three arguments: `expression`, `templateName`, and `htmlFieldName`. If you supply the expression, `null` for `templateName` (thereby telling the helper to resolve the editor template the usual way), and an empty string for `htmlFieldName`, this should render the fields without the `Elements[0].` prefix.

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.Elements[i], null, string.Empty)%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround this using the partial view. If you move your `EditorFor` to partial view (with `ElementModel` as model) there won't be generated `[0]` brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate answer, I went with HackedByChinese as this doesn't involve an extra file (the partial view) just for this case.

Comment: Of course, I have also added +1 to @HackedByChinese, I like his solution more than my ;-)